# Magento 2 Braintree compilation issue

Tags: braintree, magento2.4.1

Hi I am having difficulties getting Magento 2.4.1 to work when Braintree module is enabled.
With Braintree enabled I cannot view the product page, i get an error that begins with

> Error: Class 'Braintree\Configuration' not found

When I disable the braintree module I can access the product page ok.

When I run

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

I get the following error:

> Compilation was started.
> Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 37 secs 288.0 MiB
> In ClassReader.php line 45:
> Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [  Braintree\Transaction $transaction ] of PayPal\Braintree\Model\Report\Row\TransactionMap class
> In ClassReader.php line 34:
> Class Braintree\Transaction does not exist
> setup:di:compile

I have ran setup upgrade, clean and flush cache then tried to di:compile still issues occurs.

Short of a fresh install i cannot think of anything else that may resolve the issue.

Any help would be of great help.

Comment: did you give permissions to whole Magento installation? chmod -R 775 MagentoFolder, also try php bin/magento indexer:reindex and clean cache. Check that braintree module is correct configured.

Comment: From what I can tell every folder has permissions set to 755 and files set to 644. I have ran the indexer numerous times and issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Gene for support and as suggest by Petar, the braintree module did not install properly.

Gene advised to me run

```
composer require braintree/braintree_php:5.2.0
```

Which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should freely remove braintree and all other modules that are not essential. Check out https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all to see all the modules that you can remove freely without any issues to your magento installation.

What we do is we create our own module that has just an .json file with the same contents as the one from Yireo, where we remove the modules that we dont want to have in our Magento instance.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to do that as Braintree is our main payments processor.

Comment: Then check if braintree is properly installed. From the error messages i can see that you magento cannot find the classes. Check if there is any updates for Braintree aswell that are for Magento 2.4.1